# How to remove or hide moodle 2.8 lesson actions list item?

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle 2.8

I wants to hide/remove moodle lesson actions. Moodle lesson has following actions

Add an end of branch
Add a content page
Add a cluster
etc

I want to show only *Add a content page* & *Question* from above

How to do this?

Thanks..!